# Convert Android View#post(Runnable) to RxJava

Tags: android, android-view, rx-java, rx-android

Been using a bit of RxJava and can see its advantages. One being that anonymous inner classes get garbage-collected when a subscription is unsubscribed in `onStop()`.

Am new to RxJava so sorry if this isn't right.

Perhaps something like:

```
pager.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final int currentItem = pager.getCurrentItem(); 
        pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        pager.setCurrentItem(currentItem);
    }
});
```

becomes:

```
Observable.just(pager)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(pager -> {
        final int currentItem = pager.getCurrentItem(); 
        pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        pager.setCurrentItem(currentItem);
    });
```

Reason I ask is that I have come across a problem when rotating and updating a `ViewPager` and it turned out to an anonymous inner Runnable passed to a `post(Runnable)`. Would save time to make a static inner class with a `WeakReference` for the task.

Comment: What problem exactly where you experiencing in the first place? Reactive brings quite much of added complexity with its benefits, so it'd be smart to think if you really need it first.

Comment: I was doing a refresh of a ViewPager but it can happen that the refresh happens when the Activity is destroyed and will get a crash like this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218912

Answer (score 0):

> when do you do this runnable post?

**In short:**

RxJava is not particular helpful in this scenario and it can be done with Handler.

**More details:**

Both code segments will do pretty much the same thing, they will eventually post a runnable/action on the main thread handler (that will be processed in order with other actions queued in the main thread).

If you do it from a different thread, there can be 'race' with activity finish/destroy on the main thread, meaning the action that will make the viewpager not available anymore will be invoked BEFORE your action that require 'live' viewPager object, and that can make the crash/null exception.

It is true, that if you will unsubscribe from the observable on the main thread with the finish/destroy operation (whatever lifecycle event making the viewPager not 'live' anymore) the action will not be invoked, and crash will prevented.

It can be done similarly using [Handler.removeCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)) and instead of using View.post (that internally uses handler) using [Handler.post()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)).